# Cluster Mapbox based on Administrative Level

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to do clustering in mapbox based on administrative level?
Example : we have coordinates for a province and a district. If we click the province, it will zoom in into a bunch of the district and we can see the data from that district such as population density, etc.
If it is possible. can you give me any references?